# Absolute CSS Image — 100% Width and Height

Tags: html, css, image, background

I'm building the following website for a client based on a WP premium theme. As you can see, I'm trying to set it so that images can be applied full-screen.

http://www.dev-redakhelladi.co.uk.gridhosted.co.uk/about/

The problem I'm having is that I am now getting a horizontal scrollbar showing up when the image is there.

I've already set the image position to `absolute` so I would have thought this would prevent any scrollbar issues. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you should not load your background as `img`. Load it using `background-image` attribute on some fixed positioned element. This way, when the image is not available, you won't have an ugly browser placeholder saying [image-not-found].

Secondly, whenever you have an element set to width 100% and add a padding to it, it is going to overflow on the x axis. If you don't want that, set the `overflow-x` to hidden on it's parent, as @abforce suggested.

The best way to add a full background image is to add it as a background to a fixed positioned div which is a direct descendant of the `body` element.

Here's an example:

```
<body>
    <div class="full-background"></div>
    <!-- Here goes your content... --> 
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.full-background {
    position: fixed;
    background-image: url('link-to-your-image');
    background-size: cover;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this rule to your `body`

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to set the image as a background-image with CSS instead of an IMG element.

```
#content-wrapper {
    background-image: url('http://www.dev-redakhelladi.co.uk.gridhosted.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/iStock_000008484482Medium.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it as background image:

```
.background-photo{
    background: url('url_to_image') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the image as background in the body tag width background-size set to cover instead so the image will fit your page